# Картинка поверх элементов

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Добрый вечер!

При верстке столкнулся с такой проблемой, никак не могу вывести эту линию поверх всех элементов, так, чтобы это не перекрыло возможность взаимодействовать с блоком акций, то есть ховеры и т.д.

Как это реализовать? Заранее благодарен.

Верстка: http://smart-kids-shop.ru/dd/

Разметка:

```
<section class="akcii">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="akcia">
                    <img src="img/akcia.png" alt="">
                    <p class="title">АКЦИЯ!</p>
                    <div class="onhover">
                        <h3>СПОРТИВНАЯ МАМА</h3>
                        <hr>
                        <p>15 специальных тренировок для восстановления
                            после родов + 5 лимфодренажных массажа.
                            Программа рассчитана на 4 месяца с заморозкой</p>
                        <hr>
                        <h3>15.500 р.</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="akcia">
                    <img src="img/akcia.png" alt="">
                    <p class="title">АКЦИЯ!</p>
                    <div class="onhover">
                        <h3>СПОРТИВНАЯ МАМА</h3>
                        <hr>
                        <p>15 специальных тренировок для восстановления
                            после родов + 5 лимфодренажных массажа.
                            Программа рассчитана на 4 месяца с заморозкой</p>
                        <hr>
                        <h3>15.500 р.</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="akcia">
                    <img src="img/akcia.png" alt="">
                    <p class="title">АКЦИЯ!</p>
                    <div class="onhover">
                        <h3>СПОРТИВНАЯ МАМА</h3>
                        <hr>
                        <p>15 специальных тренировок для восстановления
                            после родов + 5 лимфодренажных массажа.
                            Программа рассчитана на 4 месяца с заморозкой</p>
                        <hr>
                        <h3>15.500 р.</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="akcia">
                    <img src="img/akcia.png" alt="">
                    <p class="title">АКЦИЯ!</p>
                    <div class="onhover">
                        <h3>СПОРТИВНАЯ МАМА</h3>
                        <hr>
                        <p>15 специальных тренировок для восстановления
                            после родов + 5 лимфодренажных массажа.
                            Программа рассчитана на 4 месяца с заморозкой</p>
                        <hr>
                        <h3>15.500 р.</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<div class="line"></div>

<section class="cta">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h1>ЗАНИМАЙСЯ БЕСПЛАТНО!</h1>
                <hr>
                <p>Заполните заявку и наш менеджер свяжется с вами в течение 10 минут.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section.akcii {
  background: #202020;
  div.akcia {
    z-index: 194;
    cursor: pointer;
    max-width: 80%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffe701 0%, #fcbf12 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffe701 0%,#fcbf12 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffe701 0%,#fcbf12 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffe701', endColorstr='#fcbf12',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    &:hover {
      z-index: 194;
      opacity: 1;
      img {
        opacity: 0.15;
        transition: 0.5s;
      }
      p.title {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: 0.5s;
      }
      div.onhover {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: 0.5s;
      }
    }
    div.onhover {
      opacity: 0;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      max-width: 60%;
      top: 80px;
      left: 20%;
      color: #fff;
      transition: 1s;
      h3 {
        font-family: "GothaBol", sans-serif;
        font-size: 24px;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
      }
      hr {
        max-width: 40%;
      }
      p {
        font-size: 14.23px;
        font-family: "GothamR", sans-serif;
      }
    }
    img {
      width: 100%;
      display: inline;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    p.title {
      top: 250px;
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 32.86px;
      font-family: "GothaBol", sans-serif;
      z-index: 1;
      left: 37%;
      top: 280px;
      letter-spacing: 3px;
      transition: 1s;
    }
  }
}

div.line {
  background: url("../img/line.png");
  position: absolute;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  top: 991px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2581px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходим такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переместить `.line` скажем в `.cta` и добавить стили:

```
.akcii, .cta {
  position: relative;
}

.akcii .container,
.cta .container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.cta .line {
  top: -650px;
}
```

Comment: Мой способ костыльный? :)

Comment: @user234223, вроде нет. Вы его тестили? Я не понимаю как добавлением одного `::before` можно добиться нужного результата, тут явно нужна работа с z-index. Хотя может ошибаюсь.

Comment: давайте я залью и увидите :D. Я только учусь всему этому ремеслу.

Comment: Посмотрите: http://smart-kids-shop.ru/dd/

Comment: @user234223, При маленькой высоте экрана "Записаться" не нажать. Но да, переместить в начало akcii логичнее, хотя зависит от адаптивности. Но сам `::before` тут роли не играет, это такой же элемент (хоть и псевдо) вставленный в блок akcii, ваш "метод" работает лишь потому, что вставлен в нужное место, вставьте .line в то же место, получите то же самое. Да и позиционировать его явно надо не относительно документа, а относительно блока, иначе адаптивность никакая, он ездит по всей странице, а по идее должен быть в одном месте всегда (между блоками).

Comment: Теперь появилась другая проблема, однако.
В блоке акций перестал работать :hover эффект, только на тексте http://victory-factory.ru/dd/

Comment: @user234223, вы забыли `.akcii .container, .cta .container { position: relative; }` Без этого `z-index` не работает (либо любого другого `position` кроме `static`)

Comment: Большое спасибо. Помогло!

Comment: @user234223, Главное используйте z-index с умом, штука хорошая, но если вставлять и тут и там, то может привести к самой непонятной каше какая только может произойти за счет стилей. Как по мне - самое опасное и "сложно поддерживаемое" свойство.

Answer (score 0):

Вставил через ::before

```
section.akcii {
  background: #202020;
  ::before {
    background: url("../img/line.png");
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2581px;
  }
  div.akcia {
    z-index: 194;
    cursor: pointer;
    max-width: 80%;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 80px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffe701 0%, #fcbf12 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffe701 0%,#fcbf12 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffe701 0%,#fcbf12 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffe701', endColorstr='#fcbf12',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    &:hover {
      z-index: 194;
      opacity: 1;
      img {
        opacity: 0.15;
        transition: 0.5s;
      }
      p.title {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: 0.5s;
      }
      div.onhover {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: 0.5s;
      }
    }
    div.onhover {
      opacity: 0;
      position: absolute;
      text-align: center;
      max-width: 60%;
      top: 80px;
      left: 20%;
      color: #fff;
      transition: 1s;
      h3 {
        font-family: "GothaBol", sans-serif;
        font-size: 24px;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
      }
      hr {
        max-width: 40%;
      }
      p {
        font-size: 14.23px;
        font-family: "GothamR", sans-serif;
      }
    }
    img {
      width: 100%;
      display: inline;
      transition: 0.5s;
    }
    p.title {
      top: 250px;
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 32.86px;
      font-family: "GothaBol", sans-serif;
      z-index: 1;
      left: 37%;
      top: 280px;
      letter-spacing: 3px;
      transition: 1s;
    }
  }
}
```